# Programming Language Syntax Parser (Convert Perl scripts to Lua)

Tags: perl, lua

Is there a generic lexer which can be used to convert 100-1000 of perl scripts to lua scripts with API changes included?

E.g. i have a c++ program that utilized perl for scripting interface - it uses things like
sub button

button.addEventLister(...)

end

now i want to change my scripting interface to lua - and i have all these perl scripts - i could write a manual parser based upon regexp etc to get a good conversation rate i believe - however i would prefer a smart solution which would make it impossible to have conversation errors between the languages (different datatypes, language syntax keywords etc)

Maybe something like this ?  http://irony.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=expression%20grammar%20sample&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Converting perl into another language? Bwahahahaha! No chance! Your program, it is trapped forever!

Comment: Highly doubt it. A perfect conversion effectively requires being able to solve the halting problem, I think.

Comment: "only perl can parse Perl" — I think you should translate by hand, as perl allows for some very interesting syntax/features not easily reproducible in other languages. Just think the very advanced Regexp engine or things like BEGIN{} blocks...

Comment: There is a way to do this: Compile to assembly, translate the assembly to Lua. Of course, then your code will be a billion times larger and you won't be able to understand it.

Comment: @Manishearth is there a Lua obfuscation challenge somewhere? :)

Comment: @Manishearth: "Compile to assembly" - Perl is never compiled to a real machine code, so there is no assembler representation. One could extract the opcodes of the perl syntax tree, but they are useless for any other interpreter, as parts will already have been executed *before* compile time.

Comment: Ah come on.. assembly? [B::C](http://search.cpan.org/~rurban/B-C-1.42/lib/B/C.pm) might be more handy for the task ;)

Comment: @Donal Fellows: Solving it in the most general case, yeah, that's a bit of a laugh. But solving it in a specific case depends on who wrote the Perl. I recently had a contract job where I had to translate tens of thousands of lines of Perl into Lua. It was actually very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a ready-made solution that does exactly what you need (especially taking into account the "API changes" that you need).

Your next best option would be finding a perl parser that can generate Abastract Syntax Trees, which you could then transform into Lua.

You could of course fork the perl parser and work from there, but it would be probably simpler to use an already-made Perl parser, like [PPI](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/PPI-1.215/). It'll allow you to manipulate the language at a higher level.

You would still need to transform the in-memory data structures generated by PPI into Lua code, via more perl. That piece is missing, and you would have to program it yourself.

If you are doing 100 scripts, it's probably not worth trying to go this route, and do the translation manually instead. If you are more near the 1000, I would say it's worth a shot.

I hope you have a way to automatically test your scripts, however. Otherwise, you are in for a lot of fun.

Comment: This PPI util is great and is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you! The dumper utility http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/PPI-1.215/lib/PPI/Dumper.pm is a great start for parsing - at least i have a tree structure now and know when conditions start and end.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is short: **No**, unless your Perl code looks and behaves like C with sigils ;-)

(You can however try to aid manual translation by applying loads of Regexes like

`s/ sub \s+ (\w+) \s* \{ /function $1/x`,

`s/ \} \s* elsif \s* \{ /elseif/x` or

`s/[@\$%]//` and the sort)

Comment: thanks but thats what i already suggested in my post "manual parser based upon regexp etc to get a good conversation"

Comment: Suggesting regexes to convert Perl into a different language? Seriously?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd have to write functions in Lua that do the same thing as Perl's operators. Even things as simple as addition behaves differently in Perl and in Lua, not to mention more complicated things like `split` and the match operator.

Once you have that done, it would actually be fairly easy to translate your Perl scripts into Lua. The problem is that the first step will take you years to complete.

A better option would be to [embed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) a Perl interpreter in your Lua process (assuming Lua allows you to link to C code, but it would greatly surprise me if you couldn't).